# NetSuite SuiteScript to modify file in the file cabinet

Tags: netsuite

We have files within the NetSuite file cabient which need to be updated (the url field has changed).  I found the noted article on this site but there is no code example to perform the requested.  It indicates to use the nlapiLoadFile and nlapiSubmitFile calls; would anyone be able to assist with a code example?

Link:
[Can Netsuite Suitescript modify a file in the file cabinet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765886/can-netsuite-suitescript-modify-a-file-in-the-file-cabinet)

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not see the URL field in the SuiteScript Records Browser:
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2011_2/index.html
I found "Folder" but the fields table does not contain URL so it looks like the field is not available for scripting.

Answer (score 3):

Ya, it seems a bit odd. The only way I found is:

1. Load The File
2. Create a file handle with:

   - Set the file name to one that you intended.
   - Set the content to intended one
3. Set the folder and submit.

***I have attached a code snippet***

```
    var file = nlapiLoadFile(file_id);
    var content = file.getValue();
    content = '...put your content...';
    file = nlapiCreateFile(file.getName(), 'FILE TYPE', content);
    file.setFolder(required_folder_id);
    nlapiSubmitFile(file);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a very useful answer and the correct one to the question imho. I was not aware of the content parameter.

Answer (score 3):

There is no special API function to edit an existing file, you could take the details of the existing file and create a new file with the same details but changing the data field only and deleting the old file.

```
var start = function(request, response)
{
    var fileId = "107524";//get the existing file id
    var file = nlapiLoadFile(fileId);
    var data = file.getValue();
    var name = file.getName();
    var folderId = file.getFolder();
    var fileType = file.getType();
    nlapiDeleteFile(fileId);//delete the older file

    data += ",this is the appended data";//change the data
    var newFile = nlapiCreateFile(name, fileType, data);//create a new file with the same details
    newFile.setFolder(folderId);
    nlapiSubmitFile(newFile);//submit it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean file instead of field?  If you use nlapiLoadFile(/path/file), you can then use getURL() to provide a link to that file.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite does not have a edit file kind of an API. You will have to load the original file, modify the contents as per your needs and then submit that data by creating a new file with same file name and inside the same folder. This simply overrides the existing file.

Here's the code sample:

```
var original = nlapiLoadFile(FILE_ID_OR_FILE_PATH_IN_FILE_CABINET);
var originalContent = original.getValue(); //Return the value (base64 encoded for binary types) of the file

var updated = nlapiCreateFile(original.getName(), FILE_TYPE, UPDATED_FILE_CONTENTS);
updated.setFolder(original.getFolder());
nlapiSubmitFile(updated);
```

Comment: What SuiteScript version is this code? There is no update-file API for SuiteScript 2.x yet?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar error when trying to modify a file using SuiteScript in Netsuite at the server-side. I was using the way explained in the documentation, where they say copying a new file through `file.copy()` with `conflictResolution: file.ConflictResolution.OVERWRITE`. However, that way didn't work for me as it neither created the file nor overwrote it. Finally, I use the following form to get it working:

```
...            
let fileNew = file.create({
                name: 'same_name_of_the_original_file',
                fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT, // change it depending the file type you will create
                contents: credentials.body,
            });

fileNew.folder = folder_id;
let fileId = fileNew.save();
...
```

So, the key is to change the folder and saving it after the file is created. After that, saving the file would overwrite the original.