# How to use different IDE with Netsuite

Tags: webstorm, netsuite, textmate

I'm admittedly new to Netsuite, so this may be obvious, although I've been unable to find anything specific one way or the other.  In fact, I don't even attend any training until next week, but I'm trying to get part of my development environment setup with one of the editors/IDEs I prefer.  I know that Netsuite offers an Eclipse plugin, but I'm not an Eclipse fan.  I'd prefer to use either WebStorm or TextMate. (I'm on MacOS Sierra)

I tried installing the WebStorm plugin, but it's throwing an exception and is not functional.  I submitted a bug on GitHub, but what I'd really like to know is if it's possible for me to write my own script to upload/download files to the cabinet, so I could just roll my own feature in TextMate.  Is this possible, and if so, how?  (Just a link to the docs is perfectly fine)

In other words, is it possible via their API, to submit changes to a script I've been working on in another editor/IDE?  Or interact with our cabinet? (Not sure if I'm using the proper NS verbiage, but hopefully you get my intent) I'm thinking about writing a Python script, that accepts a local script path as a parameter, that will then get submitted to our cabinet. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592408/netsuite-suitescript-to-modify-file-in-the-file-cabinet should get you started codewise. You'll want to use a RESTlet so that you can transfer file data between your IDE and NetSuite.

Comment: Cool.  That's pretty much just what I was looking for.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin for JetBrains IDEs (I use WebStorm specifically though) that mimics NetSuite's Eclipse plugin. Feel free to take a look. It is open source and has ~1500 downloads at the current moment.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8305?pr=

If you are the same person that opened this issue (https://github.com/Topher84/NetSuite-Tools-For-WebStorm/issues/7), it has been closed and was due to using an older version of WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like eclipse personally, so I just make my scripts in whatever and use Netsuite's script backend to upload the scripts as 'new' when I'm done. If I want to change them, simply use their backend again to 'edit' the script. You'll see a simple editor, where you can change things, or you just copy and paste what you have in there. It's a little more work than something integrated, but it does work..